# Hardening reverse SSH tunnel (via jump host)

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, reverse-proxy

When inspecting the system logs of some other issue, I noticed that I was getting lots of SSH attempts in real time. Specifically I have about [10'000 attempts daily](https://gist.github.com/fatso83/6495cfbe12986752fe49e2f9abcb6df8)!

```
$ grep Disconnected /var/log/auth.log | wc -l #since March 6
46149
```

This was quite an eye-opener to me, as I am behind a NAT and normally have 0 logon attempts. From the logs I got a clear hint as to what was going on: the logon attempts were all from `localhost`!

```
Mar 10 11:27:38 devbox sshd[11409]: Disconnected from invalid user mn 127.0.0.1 port 45822 [preauth]
Mar 10 11:27:46 devbox sshd[11426]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 127.0.0.1 port 45824 [preauth]
```

The only thing I could come up with that made sense, was that these connections originated from the reverse SSH tunnel I have established towards my jump host to be able to login to my work computer from home. And indeed, when doing `sudo systemctl stop reverse-tunnel` all activity stopped immediately! So something about my setup is fishy. Up until now, I had assumed that my setup required the client side to be able to login to the jump host using a certificate valid for that host to be allowed to initiate a connection, but this was clearly wrong!

## Setup

### The client side `.ssh/config`

```
Host jump
    HostName jumphost.somedomain.com
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jump

# local -> jump -> jump:30001 --> work
# reverse tunnel: work -> jump:22 sets up jump:30001 -> work
Host work
    ProxyJump jump
    User my-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
    HostName jumphost.somedomain.com
    Port 30001
```

The above seems fine, as that just covers the "client side" bit, telling my local computer how to connect.

### The reverse tunnel service

This is setup as a systemd service that always is running and is what actually allows inbound connections from the jump host to my work computer. This is the prime suspect.

```
# The SSH tunnel is configured mostly through options specified in the default ssh config file (such as private key)
# It needs to be copied to /etc/systemd/system/ to be picked up and then run
#    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
#    sudo systemctl enable tunnel
#    sudo systemctl start tunnel
# Original implementation: https://askubuntu.com/a/1316825/165026

[Unit]
Description=Maintain Reverse SSH Tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
User=my-user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh  -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -M 44444 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -gnNT -R 30001:localhost:22 jump
RestartSec=15
Restart=always
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I suspect this bit to be the culprit: `-R 30001:localhost:22 jump`

Answer (score 0):

## It's the server config, stupid

Obviously, port 30001 seems like it is wide open to the public on the public-facing network interface. To verify this, I tried logging on using `ssh -p 30001 clearly-wrong@jump` and indeed, this easily greppable username turned up in the logs:

```
Mar 10 14:35:46 ACME sshd[22697]: Failed password for invalid user pt from 127.0.0.1 port 45854 ssh2
Mar 10 14:36:08 ACME sshd[22705]: Failed password for invalid user cluster from 127.0.0.1 port 45856 ssh2
Mar 10 14:36:37 ACME sshd[22736]: Failed password for invalid user clearly-wrong from 127.0.0.1 port 45858 ssh2
```

An easier way is using netcat:

```
$ nc jumphost.somedomain.com 30001
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1
```

which shows the problem even easier.

*So, if I successfully manage to close this port to the public, I have closed the security hole.* Let's use `netstat` to figure out which ports it listens to:

```
$ sudo netstat -tapn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1984729/sshd: /usr/ 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2950075/sshd: ubunt
```

So it is clearly listening to all interfaces.

So let us have a look at this bit, which is executed on my work computer: `-R 30001:localhost:22 jump`. This says "open a reverse tunnel, going from port 30001 to port 22 on localhost". What seems to be missing here, is specifying which IP should listen to port 30001. If missing, it probably means *all interfaces*. Let's restrict it down to `localhost` there as well! So I connect using

```
ssh -nNT -R 127.0.0.1:30001:localhost:22 jump
```

That should take care of it?

```
$ sudo netstat -tapn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1984729/sshd: /usr/ 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2950287/sshd: ubunt
```

No, turns it out it did nothing? OK, so [reading a bit more](https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-an-ssh-tunnel-publicly-accessible) it turns out that the `sshd` config `GatewayPorts` has something to do with it (clearly forgotten that I had done this long ago), so I tried commenting it out, followed by a reload of the ssh config  and voila:

```
$ sudo service ssh reload
$ sudo netstat -tapn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1984729/sshd: /usr/ 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30001         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2950497/sshd: ubunt
```

Indeed, this fixes things:

```
$ nc -v jumphost.somedomain.com 30001
nc: connect to jumphost.somedomain.com (191.212.201.145) port 30001 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

The only tweak I needed to do now to get my `ProxyJump` definition for the ssh nick `work` to function was to adjust the `HostName` from the public hostname to `localhost`.

## Problem: I need GatewayPorts enabled for other services ...

While this makes connecting to SSH easy, I sometimes needs to expose ports running on the work computer on the jump host. Typically, if running some PHP server on the work computer and needing to debug it from home. Turns out there is a half-way option between enabled and disabled: `clientspecified`! You can read [more about it here](https://askubuntu.com/a/50075/165026).