# Using mosh with SSH jump hosts

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, mosh

I have a reverse SSH tunnel setup between `bigbox` and `jump` so that I can login into `bigbox` from where ever (it is behind a firewall) by using `jump` as a middle man. This works fine: I just `ssh bigbox` from my laptop and presto, I am in.

Now, I want to use [mosh](https://mosh.org/) to reduce lag, but I am not sure how to get it working. I have no experience with Mosh from earlier. I basically want to use SSH to setup the initial connection using my configuration and then leave it to Mosh.

Unsurprisingly, neither doing `mosh bigbox` nor `mosh --ssh="ssh bigbox" localhost` did work:

```
$ mosh bigbox
/opt/homebrew/bin/mosh: Could not connect to localhost, last tried ::1: Connection refused
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
/opt/homebrew/bin/mosh: Did not find remote IP address (is SSH ProxyCommand disabled?).
```

Here is my config:

## ~/.ssh/config

```
Host jump
    HostName jump.somedomain.com
    User jumpuser

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693885/hardening-reverse-ssh-tunnel-via-jump-host/693886#693886
Host bigbox
    ProxyJump jump
    User my_user

    # Using a reversed SSH tunnel
    HostName localhost
    Port 20001
```

Comment: Found a bunch of quite hairy threads on working with hosts behind NAT:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540128/how-to-connect-to-the-server-behind-nat-using-mosh/57948167#57948167, 
https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/48, 
https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/285

Comment: How to forward UDP traffic over TCP tunnel: https://github.com/carltonf/mosh-via-tunnel. A bit much for my feeble head